# Compute a particular solution of AX = b

Tags: linear-algebra

$A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 2 \\
        2&5&8&8&9 \\
        2&4&6&0&-1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Compute a particular solution $X_\text{particular}$ of AX = $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

This is what I have done so far:

$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}        
        1&3&5&0&2&4 \\
        2&5&8&8&9&0 \\
        2&4&6&0&-1&1 \\
        \end{array}\right]$ $\Rightarrow$ $\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}        
        1&3&5&0&2&4 \\
        0&-1&-2&8&5&-8 \\
        0&0&0&-16&-15&-15 \\
        \end{array}\right]$

$-16x_4 - 15x_5 = 15$

$\fbox {$x_4 = (15-15x_5)/16$}$

$-x_2 - 2x_3 + 8x_4 + x_5 = -8$

$\fbox {$x_2 = -8 - 2x_3 + (15 - 5x_5)/2$}$

$x_1 + 3x_2 + 5x_3 + 2x_5 = 4$

$\fbox {$x_1 = 28 + x_3 - 3[(15 - 5x_2)/2] + 2x_5$}$

Is this correct, and where do I go from here?\fbox

Comment: @Amzoti I did the row reduction until I got 3 pivots.

Comment: @Christina there is a mistake in your calculation. The last entry of third row will be 9 instead of -15

Comment: @Raven Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).